# How to use fmod and avoid precision issues

Tags: c, precision, modulus, double-precision

I'm going to boil this problem down to the simplest form:

> Let's iterate from [0 .. 5.0] with a step of 0.05 and print out 'X'
>   for every 0.25 multiplier.

```
for(double d=0.0; d<=5.0; d+=0.05) {
  if(fmod(d,0.25) is equal 0)
    print 'X';
}
```

This will of course not work since `d` will be [0, 0.05000000001, 0.100000000002, ...] causing *fmod()* to fail. Extreme example is when `d=1.999999999998` and `fmod(d,0.25) = 1`.

How to tackle this? [Here is](http://ideone.com/SnksPK) an editable online example.

Comment: Unless the step size (`0.05` here) can be represented as `2**x` (** == raised to), you will not likely get `==` for float/double variables/calculations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd solve this by simply not using floating point variables in that way:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 500; i += 5) {
  double d = i / 100.0;  // in case you need to use it.
  if ((i % 25) == 0)
    print 'X';
}
```

They're usually problematic enough that it's worth a little extra effort in avoiding them.

Answer (score 3):

In cases where you always have the same fixed decimal fraction, simply multiply by up your loop counter (by 20 in this case). When you want to access it as a double, divide by 20. In effect, you are using a hidden exponent to keep your double an integer.

In the example, I use an integer for a loop counter, assuming it has the required precision.

```
for(int i=0; i<=100; i+=1) {
  if(i % 5 == 0)
    print 'X';
  double d = (double)i / 20.0;
  // use d
}
```